# Ruby Mail Gem body text comparison

Tags: ruby, email, comparison

```
body = Mail.first.body.decoded
   if (body == 'Virus')
        puts 'Infected'
    end
```

I cant seem to get this string comparison to work, I am sending the emails like so:

```
  def send(sender, receiver,replyMessage)
    print "Sending..."
    p = properties
    mail = Mail.new do
      from     "#{sender}@#{p['mail_host']}"
      to       receiver
      body 'Virus'
    end
    mail.delivery_method :sendmail
    mail.deliver
    puts 'OK'
  end
```

I have successfully send emails like this before so I believe this code to be correct.

I have tried all combinations of : " " , ' ' , == , .eql? , (String), .to_s and nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Mail object adds white-space characters to the body so the comparison was comparing "virus" to "virus\n" so changed the if statement to if bod.include?("virus") that that solved my problem.